# Vuejs How to stop route params Type from changing when entered from url or router-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

Route params **changes** Type

- to *String* when I input from **url**
- to *Number* when  passed from **router-link**.

router.js

```
{
  path: '/post/:id',
  name: 'postdetails',
  component: () => import('./components/PostDetails.vue'),
  props: true,
}
```

when I use the "router-link" it will pass the prop as type "number"

```
  <router-link :to="{name:'postdetails', params:{id: post.id}}">
      <div class="title" @click="viewPost">
        <h4>{{post.user_username}} -</h4>
        <p>{{post.title}}</p>
      </div>
    </router-link>
```

if I **click** the element inside **router-link** it will redirect to another page and the "params.id" is type **Number**.

```
export default {
  name: "PostDetails",
  props: {
    id: Number
  },
  created() {
    console.log(this.id);
  }
};
```

But when I input it on Url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/post/1
```

the params prop becomes **String**

how can I stop the params prop Type from constantly changing?

Comment: When you navigate programmatically, the parameters get passed to the component as they are (you're passing a number), and based on them, the URL is constructed. When you access your view via URL, what it does is analyze the URL and breakdown the parameters, to then be passed to the component. That's why they change their type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to maintain the route params to a certain Type weather it was entered from a *url* or sent via *router-link* you can do it by adding a condition on the router props.

```
{
  path: '/post/:id',
  name: 'postdetails',
  component: () => import('./components/PostDetails.vue'),
  props(route) { // we keep the params.id Type from changing when entered from url
    let props = { ...route.params }
    props.id = parseInt(props.id)
    return props
  },
},
```

now the Id in the props will always be a Number Type, even if entered from url.

there is a forum from vuejs similar to this

[Router-vue, props type number didn’t cast](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/router-vue-props-type-number-didnt-cast/25774)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, you can create a computed property, which transforms the received parameter to the type you wish. Trivial implementation to convert it to string:

```
computed: {
    idStr: function() {
        return this.id + '';
    }
}
```

Check the comment I left to understand what is happening under the hood.